# Set the textView visible to the top of the containing text (scrollable textView)

Tags: android, scroll, textview

Sorry for the bad title, but I don't speak very well english. My problem (I'm working on since 2 hours) is just a detail but I want to know how to solve it, and this could help someone in the future.
I've already searched on StackOverflow and other websites, but i don't find the solution to my problem, so there it is :
I have a textView, I make it scrollable using this (second line) :

```
textViewDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
textViewDesc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

and I use these attributes of the xml file :

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:maxLines="100"
```

When I push my button on my app, it searches text from the internet and put it into my TextView. This works well, but the "failure" is the TextView starts not with the beginning of the text, but it finish with the end (I don't see the beginning, i have to scroll it).
And i think it's not obvious to a people using my app that he has to start scrolling to the top of the textView before starting his reading.

I hope you understand my problem, and help me to fix this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: PS: I've tried also with 
    textViewDesc.scrollTo(0,0);
but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `textViewDesc.setScrollY(0)` ?

Also, I've noticed that TextView scrolling is pretty unreliable. What about putting your TextView inside a ScrollView instead? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: I tried to. It is always the same thing, I see the end of my text and I have to scroll to the top

Comment: It works well with a Scrollbar, but I was thinking it was to do without this bar.

Comment: Try setScrollbarSize(0) to make it appear without the bar.